# Updating T-Mobile G1 from 1.0 to 1.6

Tags: updates, htc-dream, 1.6-donut

I have a T-Mobile G1 phone (Dev Phone) with android 1.0. To be able to install some apps, I needed to update it to 1.6. So I downloaded an update file and put it on its sdcard. But the update failed and now the problem is that I cannot boot the phone completely. First it asks for a SIM card.
[image: Without SIM card]

Although, I don't have a T-Mobile SIM card now, I could pass that stage with an AT&T SIM card.
[image: After Inserting AT&T SIM card]

Now it wants me to login to my gmail account to boot up. But I cannot connect to Internet at the moment.
[image: Google Sign in]

There is no option for wireless too. When I press menu button it just shows me the settings for APNs.
[image: APN Settings]

I believe in the newer versions of android, one can skip logging in to Google. But now I cannot even "adb shell" to copy other update files to the SD card.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this phone rooted?

Comment: The T-Mobile G1 and the ADP1 are different phones, which do you have? The reason you can't get an ADB connection is almost certainly because the "USB Debugging" settings has been switched off during the upgrade, you'd need to get into the settings and turn that back on again.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow [this guide](http://martin.iturbide.com/?page_id=191) to bypass the activation screen.  It requires reverting back to [RC29](http://www.engadget.com/2009/01/01/leaked-g1-firmware-lets-you-revert-to-rc29/) ROM (downgrading back to 1.0), and having ADB and HTC drivers installed on your PC.

The reason for installing RC29 is that this version has a flaw that treats anything you type as if it was typed into the Terminal.  You will be exploiting this flaw to enable ADB access and bring up the Settings menu, from which you can enable WiFi and activate the device.

> 1. With a Sim Card installed in your HTC G1, turn on the phone.
> 2. Plug your T-Mobile HTC G1 to you PC USB and Install Drivers on the Windows XP Machine.
> 3. Once it ask you for registration type on the keyboard the following:
>      [enter]
>      `setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1`
>      [enter]
>      *Even though you don’t see what you are typing, but you are actually
>      executing a Command on your G1 to Enable USB Debugging in Settings.
> 4. You will notice that the command worked, because Windows XP will recognize a new Hardware Device. “HTC Dream Composite ADB Intefase”. Install the driver by pointing to the folder where you downloaded the USB Drivers.
> 5. Unzip the ADB Tool software into the “c:\adb” Windows XP folder.
> 6. On Windows XP, click Start -> Run -> cmd” to Command Prompt
> 7. Type `c:\adb devices` (If your Device is Connected u will see it)
> 8. Type `c:\adb shell` (You will see a $ sign) Just Copy & Paste this into Command Prompt:
>      `am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings`
> 9. The settings screen will appear on the HTC G1 Phone. Now switch on Wi-Fi, connect to the WiFi network you have and connect to the Internet.
> 10. Now you can either Login with your existing account or create new account with Google.

After your G1 is activated, you can then flash a custom firmware (e.g. CyanogenMod) or a pre-rooted stock 1.6 ROM that will allow you to re-activate your G1 over WiFi without resorting to exploits.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the update failed. What it is asking for is your google credentials. If the update you applied failed, you most likely would be at the "android" boot and it would just loop, or you'd have a black screen.

The [ADP1 device](http://developer.htc.com/adp.html) is SIM unlocked, you said you have the Developer version of the G1. You do not need to have a T-Mobile SIM, an AT&T SIM will work.

Make sure you have the google USB drivers for the device installed.

You could also install a version of CyanogenMod on the device, I believe that allows you to use wifi to authenticate.

I found [this tutorial](http://androidforums.com/g1-support/6564-activate-stock-g1-over-wifi.html) on how authenticate via wifi, but keep in mind, this device is a couple years old now and I don't know if the files needed are still available.